# Value becomes blanks after passing in ng-bind-html through controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a angularjs page where the html contents are fetched from database and showed on html page.

```
{{ mlcontent }}
<div ng-bind-html="'{{ mlcontent }}' | trust"></div>
```

In above code snippet the first line content is being populated as from database. but in the second line the value **mlcontent**  is being blank.

To test the ng-bind-html, I passed the hardcoded values as below and it worked as expected.
`<div ng-bind-html="'<li> Some value</li> | trust"></div>`

Just to add : trust is a filter to receive html data on page

```
app.filter("trust", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(htmlCode){
        console.log("htmlCode"+ htmlCode + "\n"+ $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode));
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
  }
}]);
```

```
 **SOLUTION:
    <div ng-bind-html="mlcontent' | trust">**
```

Comment: Do you have `$sanitize` available and activated ?

Comment: Don't have to do `'{{ mlcontent }}' | trust` you can do `mlcontent | trust`, it's an expression.

Comment: You can do this easily with help of `ngSanitize` module as a sample given  below

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$sce` and you can do this with help of `ngSanitize` module as below.

For `ngSanitize` module, you have to add the below angularjs library,

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.mlcontent = '<li> Some value</li>';
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-bind-html="mlcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was doing the mistake of passing the "mlcontent" in {{ }} braces, which ng-bind-html is not accepting.  Now its working fine